# Ubuntu 22.04,Boot takes around 1:45min, snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: status=1/FAILURE

Tags: boot, 22.04, snap

New to this forum. This is my 1st question. Sorry if I'm putting question at wrong place..

Question :
Boot takes too long

```
snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

seems to be problem. Seeing messages related to this in log file multiple times.
log file attached. Any suggestions to solve problem?

```
journalctl -b0 --system _COMM=systemd gives

Sep 09 12:20:16 s systemd[1]: Startup finished in 8.285s (firmware) + 6.141s (loader) + 5.816s (kernel) + 1min 10.431s (userspace) = 1min 30.674s.
==========================================================================================================
Sep 09 12:20:17 s systemd[3280]: Starting flatpak document portal service...
Sep 09 12:20:17 s systemd[3280]: Starting sandboxed app permission store...
Sep 09 12:20:17 s systemd[3280]: Started sandboxed app permission store.
Sep 09 12:20:17 s systemd[3280]: Started flatpak document portal service.
Sep 09 12:20:18 s systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_ikQu4B.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: **snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service**: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: Started Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
Sep 09 12:20:21 s systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:21 s systemd[3280]: Started Tracker file system data miner.
Sep 09 12:20:22 s systemd[3280]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Sep 09 12:20:22 s systemd[3280]: Reached target Main User Target.
Sep 09 12:20:22 s systemd[3280]: Startup finished in 13.985s.
Sep 09 12:20:27 s systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Sep 09 12:20:27 s systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Sep 09 12:20:28 s systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Sep 09 12:20:28 s systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Sep 09 12:20:28 s systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Sep 09 12:20:28 s systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 09 12:20:28 s systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 09 12:20:29 s systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Sep 09 12:20:30 s systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Sep 09 12:20:31 s systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Sep 09 12:20:34 s systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Sep 09 12:20:34 s systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Sep 09 12:20:40 s systemd[1]: Started Session 2 of User sam.
Sep 09 12:20:45 s systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:52 s systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_8kpjQt.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:55 s systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:55 s systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Consumed 7.049s CPU time.
Sep 09 12:21:01 s systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 125...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping PipeWire Media Session Manager...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping Tracker file system data miner...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping flatpak document portal service...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[1]: run-user-125-gvfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopped PipeWire Media Session Manager.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: xdg-document-portal.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=20/n/a
....
```

systemd-analyze gives

```
Startup finished in 8.285s (firmware) + 6.141s (loader) + 5.816s (kernel) + 1min 10.431s (userspace) = 1min 30.674s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 10.406s in userspace
```

systemd-analyze blame gives

```
34.477s snapd.service
25.052s udisks2.service
21.544s systemd-journal-flush.service
19.780s tor@default.service
18.575s networkd-dispatcher.service
16.884s ModemManager.service
16.210s dev-sda3.device
15.600s cups.service
13.858s dev-loop26.device
13.815s accounts-daemon.service
13.358s dev-loop14.device
12.842s dev-loop23.device
12.635s dev-loop27.device
12.559s dev-loop24.device
12.513s dev-loop22.device
12.453s dev-loop18.device
12.193s dev-loop13.device
12.097s dev-loop19.device
11.898s dev-loop17.device
11.365s dev-loop11.device
11.319s dev-loop9.device
11.270s dev-loop8.device
11.078s dev-loop16.device
10.937s dev-loop3.device
```

chain dependency gives

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 10.406s
└─multi-user.target @1min 10.405s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 8.592s +1.811s
    └─snapd.service @34.109s +34.477s
      └─basic.target @33.710s
        └─sockets.target @33.709s
          └─snapd.socket @33.704s +3ms
            └─sysinit.target @33.578s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @33.220s +355ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @32.132s +1.029s
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @10.585s +21.544s
                    └─systemd-journald.service @9.810s +771ms
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @9.796s
                        └─-.mount @9.747s
                          └─-.slice @9.747s
```

```
some failed and deactivated messages from log

Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Job sssd-nss.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-autofs.socket: Job sssd-autofs.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-pac.socket: Job sssd-pac.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-pam.socket: Job sssd-pam.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-pam-priv.socket: Job sssd-pam-priv.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-ssh.socket: Job sssd-ssh.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Job sssd-sudo.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Sep 09 12:19:48 s systemd[1]: Started Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Sep 09 12:24:09 s systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Sep 09 12:24:10 s systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.

Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:19 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[3280]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: xdg-document-portal.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[3280]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Sep 09 12:19:36 s systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:36 s systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_blk.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:36 s systemd[1]: modprobe@pstore_zone.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:36 s systemd[1]: modprobe@ramoops.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:37 s systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:37 s systemd[1]: modprobe@mtdpstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:38 s systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:41 s systemd[1]: e2scrub_reap.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: secureboot-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: gpu-manager.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:43 s systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:47 s systemd[1]: tmp-syscheck\x2dmountpoint\x2d977763172.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:19:51 s systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:04 s systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:06 s systemd[1]: dmesg.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:16 s systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:18 s systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_ikQu4B.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:20 s systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:21 s systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:45 s systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:52 s systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_8kpjQt.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:20:55 s systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:01 s systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:05 s systemd[1]: run-user-125-gvfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:06 s systemd[1]: user@125.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:06 s systemd[1]: run-user-125-doc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:06 s systemd[1]: run-user-125.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:06 s systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@125.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:22 s systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:28 s systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:21:34 s systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 09 12:24:10 s systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Comment: Looks like a `snapd` issue. See [here](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd-desktop-integration/issues/23).